# Kivy Spinner Autoupdate

Tags: python, spinner, kivy

I have a spinner in kivy that I cannot seem to get the "text_autoupdate" feature working. The documentation can be found here: https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.spinner.html

My .py code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, BooleanProperty

class Port_Selection(Widget):   # list all serial ports
    ports = ["[None]"]
    selection = ListProperty(['hit refresh'])

    def port_refresh(self):
        port = ["1","2","3"]
        if port == []:          # if none found
            message = {"None"}  # return "none"
            port = message
        self.ports = port
        print self.ports

class SensorTest(Widget):
    pass

class Sensor(App):
    def build(self):
        return SensorTest()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Sensor().run()
```

And my .kv code:

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

<Port_Selection>:
    Spinner: 
        text: 'Select Port'
        text_autoupdate: True
        values: root.ports
        pos: root.x,root.y

    Button:
        text: 'Refresh Ports'
        pos: root.x+100, root.y
        on_press: root.port_refresh();

<SensorTest>:
    Label:
        font_size: 45
        center_x: root.width/2
        center_y: root.top - 50
        text: "Sensor Testing"

    Port_Selection:
        pos: self.pos
```

How do I get the "text_autoupdate" feature working properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to define ports as ListProperty

Change:
`ports = ["[None]"]`

To:
`ports = ListProperty(["[None]"])`

Comment: Thank you! I figured it was something simple like that, I'm just new to kivy.

Comment: @Molorius no problem. Wellcome to kivy, it will be alot of fun :)